# TS Compile fails silently

Tags: typescript, angular, typescript1.8

I've included `ng2-semantic-ui` in my `package.json`, version `^0.2.3`, and originally I had a component that looked like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Title} from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {HomeTreeComponent} from './tree';
import {UserPhotoComponent} from "./userphoto.component";

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/home/index.html',
    providers: [Title],
    directives: [HomeTreeComponent, UserPhotoComponent]
})
export class HomeIndexComponent {
    constructor(title: Title) {
        title.setTitle('Welcome');
    }
}
```

Which compiles nicely and gives a javascript file as expected. But as soon as I add `import {TAB_DIRECTIVES} from "ng2-semantic-ui/ng2-semantic-ui";` to the imports and `TAB_DIRECTIVES` to the `directives` things go wrong.
But, I'm not getting any compilation errors from `tsc` - in fact the errorlevel (running node on windows) is 0 and it prints neither errors or warnings, and all other TS files are compiled properly.

Other files are compiled properly, just not this file. Have I overlooked something? I have added an appropriate `map` in the systemjs config to load it, but I don't think that comes into play until and unless it loads in a browser.

Comment: have you tried any thing other than TAB_DIRECTIVES from ng2-semantic-ui ?

Comment: Yes, everything appears to give the same issue.

Comment: I used semantic-ui in my angular2 project but not ng2-semantic-ui. So if you want ,I can share my work around with semantic-ui :)

Comment: @pdfarhad Please do :) I have semantic-ui otherwise as well - just not any that require javascript to work...

Answer (score 0):

I used semantic-ui in my non angular-cli project by keeping the  semantic.min.css under resource folder. I dont need to configure any package.json or system.config.js. And show the path in the index.html. Here goes a screenshot

[image]

Now in my component where I need to use semantic-ui, I code like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-semantic',

  template: `
     <div class="ui tab" data-tab="first">
          My First Tab
     </div>
     <div class="ui tab" data-tab="other">
           Other content
     </div>
  `
})
```

angular version of my project is 2.0.0-rc.1

Comment: But the tab is a JavaScript component in semantic - if I'm not mistaken, so I can't really see that this would work as desired.